# sympy issue solving a linear system

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, sympy

I am using Python v.3.6 running on the Jupyter QtConsole.  I am attempting to do some linear algebra on a dataset using Sympy for a personal project linking predictions with survey scores.

In essence, I set up an augmented matrix, with N = 14 linear equations and M = 5 unknowns, and am trying to solve the system.  My problem is that when I use the solve_linear_system command on my augmented matrix, I don't get any output for my code:

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix, solve_linear_system
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, u, v
system = Matrix(((1,1,-1,0,0,1),(1,1,-1,0,0,2),(0,0,-1,0,-1,3),
(0,0,-1,0,-1,2),(0,0,0,1,0,1),(1,0,1,1,-1,2),(0,0,-1,0,-1,2),(1,0,1,0,0,1),
(1,1,1,0,1,3),(1,1,1,0,0,2),(-1,1,0,0,-1,3),(1,-1,-1,-1,0,2),(-1,1,1,1,-1,3),
(0,-1,0,0,0,2))) 
solve_linear_system(system, x, y, z, u, v)
>>
```

Can someone explain what might be the issue and how to remedy the situation? I have tried other matrices and it seems to work with them, so is there something fundamentally wrong with what I am asking Sympy todo or is it the method? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is there are no solutions to the augmented system in reference.
(probably too many constraints, you could try to relax it by eliminating some of the superfluous equations)

If you stare at your matrix for a little while, you will find that there are incompatible equations, for instance, rows 2 & 3: (0,0,-1,0,-1,3), (0,0,-1,0,-1,2), or rows 0 and 1: (1,1,-1,0,0,1),(1,1,-1,0,0,2). There may also be redundant ones.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response, yet I tried 7 equations (the ones where the last value didn't equal 2) and still no output, any more than that and worry about some information loss.  But if that is the only solution, I can consider looking into it more?

Comment: If you stare at your matrix for a little while, you will find that there are incompatible equations, for instance, rows 2 & 3: `(0,0,-1,0,-1,3), (0,0,-1,0,-1,2)`, or rows 0 and 1: `(1,1,-1,0,0,1),(1,1,-1,0,0,2)`. There may also be redundant ones.

Comment: Right that makes sense.  Yet given I tried it also with all equations excluding the ones that equal 2, wouldn't it still be able to find a solution?

Comment: Er nvm I realized that different equations have similar answers, so in effect even with the 3s, there's probably no solution.  Maybe I need to try a different strategy.